# how to put JavaScript value in html

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript Code

```
    function load()
    {
        var s = window.location.href;
        var temp_img_url=s.split("?");
        var img_url=temp_img_url[1];


    }
```

html code

```
 <img id="bigpic" src=" " style="display: none; ">
```

I am trying to put img_url in src.
What is the way to do that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add this line at the end of your load() function:

```
document.getElementById('bigpic').src=img_url;
```

this is from memory (my js is a little rusty) but should do the trick.

It uses the `getElementById()` method to get the element with the ID of `bigpic` (your image element) and sets the `src` attribute to the value of your `img_url` variable.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find the element:

```
element = document.getElementById("bigpic");
```

Then you can change the `src` attribute of that element:

```
element.setAttribute("src", img_url);
```